# Does Haystack support multi cores cross cores search with SOLR 5.3?

Tags: solr, django-haystack, solr5

Does Haystack support multi cores cross cores search with SOLR 5.3? I have three cores, core0, core1 and core2 in SOLR. How can I implement cross core search in Haystack? How can I set the Haystack Connections URL? Thanks!